# The request Timed Out Error

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I am getting the below mentioned error while using WCF.

The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:00:59.9843750. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I have been using below mentioned Web.Config file for WCF.

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
      <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
        <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
        <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>  


<system.diagnostics>

    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Error,ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
                <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
                <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
                    <filter type="" />
                </add>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="E:\DB_Syncronization\DATABASESYNCHRONIZATION\DBSyncWcfService\web_tracelog.svclog"
            type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>

<system.web>
    <!--
        Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
        symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
        affects performance, set this value to true only 
        during development.
    -->


  <compilation debug="true">

      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->

  <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </controls>
  </pages>

  <httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4"
              type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
      <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
    </compiler>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<!--
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  <modules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

```
<client />
  <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
              sendTimeout="00:10:00">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <reliableSession enabled="true" />
              <security mode="None">
                  <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                  <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                      establishSecurityContext="false" />
              </security>
          </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>  
  <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DBSyncWcfService.Service1Behavior"
    name="DBSyncWcfService.DBSyncService">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
      name="ABC" contract="DBSyncWcfService.IDBSyncContract" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.5.161/DBSyncWcfService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DBSyncWcfService.Service1Behavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <windowsAuthentication allowAnonymousLogons="true"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the binding configuration for the service, did you ammend the timeout values for the client likewise?

Comment: I have the below mentioned vakues for Client.

Comment: <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>.I have changed the Web Service receiveTimeout from ""00:01:00" to "00:10:00".Do I ned to do iisreset on Server afterr deployment.

Comment: IIS will restart if you change the web.config. I´m a little bit confused by your web.config excerpts, is the second config your client configuration? If so, I dont see a client endpoint configured, did it got lost during posting?

Comment: string endpoint = DBSyncXMLUtil.getSystemParameter(DBSyncXMLUtil.getDocumnetRoot(), "ServiceURL");//Getting data from Xml//     client = new DBSyncProxy.SqlSyncProviderProxy(endpoint);

Comment: I understand that you instantiate the client proxy in code, how do you tell the client proxy which binding configuration to use? The timeout error you´re seeing sounds like the default timeout, so my guess is you either did´nt tell it to use your changed binding configuration or you have a typo.

Comment: No.I have used below code to communicate further with the Service.

Comment: public SqlSyncProviderProxy(string endPointURL){WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;binding.ReliableSession.Enabled = true;binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647;binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647;binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647;binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647;

Comment: ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IDBSyncContract>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPointURL));dbProxy = factory.CreateChannel();this.dbProxy = dbProxy as IDBSyncContract; binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647;binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;

Comment: Have a look at the binding.SendTimeout, increasing the value should fix your problem. If it doesn´t send me mail so we can discuss this in chat

Comment: @Dominik let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2012/discussion-between-sachin-kulkarni-and-dominik)